# Unable to Parse HTML by using JSoup

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, jsoup

I want to data fetch HTML from the Website to download a video of 480p. But it's not working. I am using an Async Class for this purpose. Here my doInBackground Method:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
              //  DOWNLOAD_URL="http://topvideodownloader.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymotion.com%2Fvideo%2Fx7nctdj"
                Log.i("DownloadActivity", DOWNLOAD_URL);
                Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(DOWNLOAD_URL)
                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .timeout(12000)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();
                Document doc = response.parse();
                Log.i("DownloadActivity",doc.toString());
//                title = doc.select("div.title").text();
//                Log.e("Main", title);
//                String atag= doc.select("a.vd-down btn btn-default btn-download").attr("href");
//                matag = atag;
//                Log.e("Main", matag);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But method is fetching the complete HTML. It fetch only first few Lines of it. I also tried to fetch with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(DOWNLOAD_URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
```

But with this method. It fetch not even a single line.

I dont know what i am doing wrong?? Please help me. much appreicated

Comment: check below one

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //show progress bar
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
          try {
              //  DOWNLOAD_URL="http://topvideodownloader.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymotion.com%2Fvideo%2Fx7nctdj"
                 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(DOWN_URL)
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .timeout(0)
                .get();

                Log.i("DownloadActivity",doc.toString());
//                title = doc.select("div.title").text();
//                Log.e("Main", title);
//                String atag= doc.select("a.vd-down btn btn-default btn-download").attr("href");
//                matag = atag;
//                Log.e("Main", matag);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "success";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result.equals("success"))
         //stop progress bar
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201808/discussion-on-answer-by-kam1234-unable-to-parse-html-by-using-jsoup).